# Should potentially close worthy questions in the First Post and Low Quality Post review queues stay there?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review

Given that these queue are mostly empty on Stackoveflow and the Close Queue is so big.

When an item in the “First post” or “Low quality Post” queue is voted to be closed, should it remain in the queue until it has had enough reviews to be removed from the Close Queue?

(Remember that a lot of people only “work” the shorter queues)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. They remain for as long as it takes reviewers to review it, reviewing in one queue does not remove any item from other queue as far as I know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard,  But what does “reviewers to review it” mean?   Is it removed as soon as the first close vote is cast, or left for a fixed number of people to review it?

Comment: In first post review, one user is enough (either do some action and click "I'm Done" or just click "No Action Needed") in low quality, either one user who click "No Action Needed" or six click "Recommend Deletion". Again, close votes are not relevant in any of those queues.

Comment: @ShadowWizard,Voting to close is often an action that is taken, should “I done” after a vote to close remove the item from the queue, or should it remain in the queue for long enough to get all the close votes that are needed, or to get a few “No actions needed”

Comment: The First and Low Quality posts queue is a low reputation queue so I would wager that most users who review it don't have the ability to cast close votes, such as myself.

Comment: @Amicable, The interesting quesions is how many of the reviewer do have the ability to cast close votes.

Answer (score 8):

Users in those queues are not required to have 3k reputation, and as such may not have the vote to close privilege.  They also won't have the UI designed to more effectively review close votes, unlike the close vote queue.

Trying to move the close vote reviewing of such posts over to those queues will only reduce the efficiency of the reviewing, not improve it.

Comment: Is “efficiency” an issue if there is unused “effort” being put into a given queue that could be harvested **?**

Answer (score 4):

Closing is not the purpose of the First Posts queue.  It is simply to give a more experienced member the ability to look at the post and decide if it needs additional attention.

If someone reviewing a post in that queue votes or flags it to close, then it goes immediately to the close queue where an appropriate level of attention can be given to it.

And leaving a post in the First Post queue can have a detrimental effect.  Because voting is enabled in that queue, the extra views that the post gets can result it that post getting an unfair level of attention (similar to the Meta-effect) and can result in it getting more upvotes or downvotes than similar posts.  This is especially problematic for answers because it can skew the voting and allow a post by a first time user to get more upvotes than a similar or better answer on the same question.

The voting issue is actually one of the reasons why it only takes 1 action to kick it out of the queue.  You don't want too many extra reviews of a specific post.

Comment: Voting is how we teach users what we like, should we not be giving new users more teaching?

Comment: @IanRingrose I have less of an issue with this for questions simply because questions are rarely compared against each other using score as a metric, but for answers, voting is used to rank answers so if 2 answers posted at the same time, one by a new user and one not, the votes might get skewed due to the extra views on the first post.  That ruins the intent of the voting on answers.

Comment: Question allready have diffent logic to answers in the queues,  the current rules seem to work OK for questions.